# knockout.js foreach binding on object > object > array

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following knockout structure on an object stored in an observable called "equipment" (taken from ko.toJSON):

```
{
    "id":4,
    "name":"foo",
    "access":{
        "equipmentId":4,
        "whitelist":[
            {
                "id":22,
                "username":"someone", 
                "name":"a name"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can i bind a foreach in my HTML so that i can loop over the whitelist? 
I've tried the following which throws a binding error:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: equipment.access.whitelist">
```

I've also tried doing this which does not throw an error, but also does not loop:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: equipment().access.whitelist">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the with-binding, like so:

```
<div data-bind="with: equipment().access">
                <div data-bind="foreach: whitelist">
```

Comment: I don't know what you solved, because for me the code was working http://jsfiddle.net/auqnkvu9/

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I assume `access` was/is an observable thus `equipment.access.whitelist` caused an undefined issue and `equipment().access.whitelist` bound the foreach to undefined which provided nothing to loop over.

Comment: @Origineil there's some underlying issue in your code, because you shouldn't need `with` for that

Comment: You might be right, i had made an error in the code elsewhere that i didn't notice and solve until after this markup solved my original problem. It might be (probably is) related, i'll check it later today and revise my answer.